# to get android manifest meta data value by python xpath

Tags: python, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xiaomi.oga">
        ...
        <meta-data
            android:name="xxx"
            android:value="xxx" >
        </meta-data>

        <meta-data
            android:name="OTA_TYPE"
            android:value="daily_build_test" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

I want get the daily_build_test above by python

So far, I tried:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import os
ns='{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}'
nametag=ns+'name'
categorytag='category'
packagetag='package'

class XmlParser:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.tree = None
        self.root = None

    def __parse(self):
        if self.tree is None or self.root is None:
            parser = ET.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
            self.tree = ET.parse(self.file, parser)
            self.root = self.tree.getroot()

    def gettree(self):
        self.__parse()
        return self.tree

    def getroot(self):
        self.__parse()
        return self.root

def get_meta_data(parser):
    tree = parser.gettree()
    #value = tree.xpath('/manifest/application//meta-data[@*=\'OTA_TYPE\']/@*[2]')
    NS = {'android' : 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'}
    value = tree.xpath('/manifest/application/meta-data[@a:name=\'OTA_TYPE\']/@a:value', namespace=NS)
    print '%s' %(value)
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = os.environ['PYTHON_ARG']
    parser = XmlParser(file)
    meta_data = get_meta_data(parser)
    print '%s' %(meta_data)
```

and I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 44, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 37, in get_meta_data
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2272, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:70786)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 352, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:179055)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 95, in lxml.etree._XPathContext.registerVariables (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:175335)
  File "src/lxml/extensions.pxi", line 614, in lxml.etree._wrapXPathObject (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:171074)
lxml.etree.XPathResultError: Unknown return type: dict
```

or ['daily_build_test']
when the commentted line :

```
value = tree.xpath('/manifest/application//meta-data[@*=\'OTA_TYPE\']/@*[2]')
```

is applied

I don't want the brackets the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `tree.xpath` is `namespaces`, not `namespace`.  So:

```
NS = {'a' : 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'}
value = tree.xpath('/manifest/application/'
                   'meta-data[@a:name=\'OTA_TYPE\']/@a:value',
                   namespaces=NS)
```

Also note that you were using the key `android` in your `NS` dictionary, but `a:` in your query.  The example above corrects the dictionary so that it matches the prefix you're using.

Comment: You are right, and still it prints ['daily_build_test'],
and I found the reason, that is :
value is a list,
NS = {'a' : 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'}
value = tree.xpath('/manifest/application/'
                   'meta-data[@a:name=\'OTA_TYPE\']/@a:value',
                   namespaces=NS)
value[0] is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks to larsks, I finally get I want by:*


def get_meta_data(parser):
    tree = parser.gettree()
    NS = {'a' : 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'}
    value = tree.xpath('/manifest/application/meta-data[@a:name=\'OTA_TYPE\']/@a:value', namespaces=NS)
    print '%s' %(value[0]) 
    # NOTE value is a list of length 0.
    return value[0]
```